# Replace entry from database using hidden input fields - Entity Framework

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a button dropdown that displays a persons name and their city on each line, which is read in from a database.

[image]

The purpose of this is for a user to click on an item in the dropdown and have it replace the users name in the database with their own, but only for that row.

I feel like the code is correct, but nothing is happening when I click a user's name so there must be something wrong or missing.

Now, I've tried this two ways (because I'm not sure whats correct for this situation), but they have both failed.

Attempt 1:

Code in view:

```
        using (Html.BeginForm("OverrideLock", "Branch", FormMethod.Post))
     {
         <div class="btn-group">
             <button type="button" id="overrideLock" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                 Override <span class="caret"></span>
             </button>
             <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                 @foreach (var person in Model.Where(person => person.userName != null))
                 {
                     <li class="overrideListItem">
                         <input type="hidden" name="personUsername" value="@person.userName"/>
                         <input type="hidden" name="personCity" value="@person.city"/>
                         <a>@person.city <span class="personToOverride"><b>@person.userName</b></span></a>
                     </li>
                 }
             </ul>
         </div>
     }
```

Controller Code:

```
   [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult OverrideLock(string personUsername, string personCity)
    {
        var context = new PortalEntities();
        var personToRemove = context.LockBranches.Where(p => p.userName == personUsername && personCity == p.Branch.city);
        var currentUser = HttpContext.User.Identity.Name;
        foreach (var person in personToRemove)
        {
            context.Entry(person).CurrentValues.SetValues(currentUser);
        }

        //context.LockBranches.Remove(personToRemove.FirstOrDefault());
        context.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

Attempt 2:

View Code:

```
        <div class="btn-group">
        <button type="button" id="overrideLock" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            Override <span class="caret"></span>
        </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            @foreach (var person in Model.Where(person => person.userName != null))
            {
                <li class="overrideListItem">
                    <input type="hidden" name="personUsername" value="@person.userName"/>
                    <input type="hidden" name="personCity" value="@person.city"/>
                    <a>@person.city <span class="personToOverride"><b>@person.userName</b></span></a>
                </li>
            }
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Controller Code:

```
        public void OverrideLock(string personUsername, string personCity)
    {
        var context = new PortalEntities();
        var personToRemove = context.LockBranches.Where(p => p.userName == personUsername && personCity == p.Branch.city);
        var currentUser = HttpContext.User.Identity.Name;
        foreach (var person in personToRemove)
        {
            context.Entry(person).CurrentValues.SetValues(currentUser);
        }

        //context.LockBranches.Remove(personToRemove.FirstOrDefault());
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
```

Either way nothing is happening at all.

Thanks for your help! Let me know if there is any additional information I can add.

Comment: just clicking a menu item will not cause a post.. where is your submit button or change even to call form.submit()?

Comment: I didn't even realize. I am still new to this. I can add a submit button if that's the only way I can get this to work

Comment: you'd need to do more than that i'm afraid.  I think you'd end up getting back all names and city since you're not disabling the ones that are not selected

Answer (score 1):

Forget my last answer. Can you use jquery?

Try this (with jquery):

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("OverrideLock", "Branch", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "override-form" }))
{
    <div class="btn-group">
        <button type="button" id="overrideLock" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            Override <span class="caret"></span>
        </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            @foreach (var person in Model.Where(person => person.userName != null))
            {
                <li class="overrideListItem" data-username="@person.userName" data-city="@person.city">
                    <a>@person.city <span class="personToOverride"><b>@person.userName</b></span></a>
                </li>
            }
        </ul>

        <input type="hidden" name="personUsername" value="" />
        <input type="hidden" name="personCity" value="" />

        <script>
            $(function () {

                $(".overrideListItem").click(function () {

                    var userName = $(this).attr("data-username");
                    var city = $(this).attr("data-city");

                    $("input[name='personUsername']").val(userName);
                    $("input[name='personCity']").val(city);
                    $("#override-form").submit();

                });
            });
        </script>
    </div>
}
```

Comment: Okay, can you elaborate a little?

Comment: Thank you, this should work. I am getting an error "The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'branchId'", which I am still trying to figure out.

Comment: I don't know where you are using branchId, maybe you added something to routes. If you added it to action OverrideLock in Branch controller probably you need to add the extra parameter branchId to action and to BeginForm method like: `@using (Html.BeginForm("OverrideLock", "Branch", new { branchId = Model.SomeFieldWhichDetermineBranchId}, FormMethod.Post, new { id = "override-form" }))`.